# HBase: creating a hbase table with multiple columns in a column family

Tags: hbase

The first time I create a HBase table I want the table to be created with multiple columns in the following way(I know the following way wont work looking for similar kind of way)..

```
create 'table_name','col_family:column1','col_family:column2'
```

is this possible? Apart from using the put command and adding a column to a columnfamily dynamically is there any other way??

Comment: Why do you need to add a column before `Put`? HBase is schemaless, thus it is against its logic.

Comment: actually i just need a hbase table to be created with colum_famliy and columns in it and a hive table will be pointed to it. My pyspark code inserts into the hive table and internally records will be inserted into the hbase table..

Comment: Isn't specifying schema in Hive enough?

Comment: if i do so hive throws an error.. because there wont be any columns in the column family, While creating the hbase table and if want to have column families i have to use 'put' but, my requirement is to  add columns at the time of creating the table itself not using 'put'.. is it possible??

Answer (score 1):

This is no possible. The column name under column family will be given only when we are inserting value. if you want to add column to CF try below.

```
put 'table_name', 'rowid','cf1:col1','Associate'
put 'table_name', 'rowid','cf1:col2','Hbase'

put 'table_name', 'rowid2','cf1:col1','PA'
put 'table_name', 'rowid2','cf1:col2','Hbase ,Hadoop'
put 'table_name', 'rowid2','cf1:col3','1'
```

For CF1 column family col3 column value is null.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is against HBase logic and it is not possible. I went through documentation and did not find any solution. In my understanding, column family is meta-data, but column qualifier may contain data similarly to cell value. Thus, if you don't have data you don't have column qualifier.